# Converting Dates between Calendars in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following snippet of Code for Convert Gregorian Date to Hijri Date.

```
public static string GregoriantoHijri(DateTime gregorianDate)
{
    CultureInfo arCI = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
    var hijriCalendar = new HijriCalendar();
    hijriCalendar.HijriAdjustment = App_Code.StoreRetrieveSettingsAssist.getHA();
    arCI.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = hijriCalendar;  //CODE FAILS HERE
    string hijriDate = gregorianDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", arCI);

    return hijriDate;
}
```

*This code runs perfectly for my Windows Mobile App which is also posted on Store.
However the same code is giving me issues in Xamarin.Android*

The Error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Not a valid calendar for the given culture.
>   Parameter name: value

I don't understand why codes using same .NET base class have issues on different platforms. Can you suggest a workaround cause this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If I remember correctly than the counting on android is different than in .NET. January is 0 not 1. So the question is: What is the provided date for the gregorianDate parameter when the exception occures?

Comment: @tequilaslammer I am using whatever date is today for Gregorian. Later I plan to add features to convert any date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime).  It is supposedly more robust than the native .NET datetime handling, and is supposed to support [Hijri](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/calendars.html).